# PS COMMAND ERROR "error: improper list" Linux

Tags: linux, bash, loops, command-line

I have the following issue. Im trying to use the PS command within a bash script to determine what users are doing what on my server, using the following:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                 
users=`who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ','`
for i in "${users[@]}"
   do
     echo "this log belongs to "${i}" " >> /var/log/testing; ps -U $i -u $i u   >>  /var/log/testing
   done
```

where the command "ps -U $i -u $i u"  will bring **USER,PID %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND**

but I got the following error:  **error: improper list**

Now... I tried to enclose the ps command like this:

```
"'ps -U $i -u $i u'"
```

And the **error: improper list**  went away but the error **command not found** came up

I tried to export the absolute path for the PS command in my bash script like this:

**export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"**

but now I have the following error: **No such file or directory** but in fact all of the directories involved in the script do exists.

what am I doing wrong?
What do I need to do in order to get the command

"ps -U $i -u $i u"

to work inside bash?

thanks for the help

Comment: `var=$(anything)` or its older backtick-based equivalent doesn't create a list or array, it creates a _string_. `readarray -t users < <(command_that_creates_one_line_per_entry)`, by contrast, will make `users` actually an array (note that your `tr` is wrong, because you want your entries separated by newlines, not commas).

Comment: That said, bash doesn't create an "improper list" error when you make that mistake (instead, it just treats your whole string as a single list entry) -- so your shell is clearly not bash. Are you maybe using zsh instead, or is the message from a linter/IDE/static-checking tool instead of the shell itself?

Comment: Also, note that you can't use `“` in place of `"`, or `‘` in place of `'`; bash only accepts regular ASCII quotes, not "smart quotes", as valid syntax.

Comment: (The reason you get "command not found" when you put your whole command in quotes is that then you're looking for an executable file with all the arguments and spaces _as part of the filename_, and of course no such executable exists)

Comment: BTW, http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend; so is xtrace (`bash -x yourscript`, to get a log of the commands the shell is running).

Comment: That is correct regarding the quotation, that was a mistake in the question, I already edited. Thanks. I did try bash -x mybash and thats for debugging thats how I got the errors detailed above

Comment: Concretely: `readarray -t users < <(who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u)`

Comment: BTW, including the actual xtrace log in the question would be good form; that would let us see where in execution the error was emitted.

Comment: Also, you probably want `"this log belongs to \"${i}\" "` -- to make the inner quotes not be treated as syntax you need to either quote or escape them. (To quote double quotes, you need to use single quotes, and you can use single quotes to quote double quotes; so you could `echo 'this log belongs to "'"$i"'"'` f/e, having a single-quoted string `this log belongs to "`, then a double-quoted string `$i`, then a single-quoted string `"` -- in bash, quoting types are character-by-character)

Comment: With the xtrace it just gives  ps -U test,: command not found, everything executes just fine but  it dies in teh execution of the PS command (that i just posted above)

Comment: the intention is to get all the users and its receptive commands that they are using within the server and forward that output to a file for further analysis, thats why i need PS because it gives me info I need for the script to work

Comment: It sounds like you haven't taken the quotes back out. You still need to do that. It's just `ps -U "$i" -u "$i" u` (assuming you've verified those arguments). No extra quotes around the whole thing.

Comment: Quoting the command of course does not make sense. The first approach looks reasonable, provided that the value of `i` is correct. I would put a `set -x` before entering the loop; have a look at the output. Also, for the safe side, do a `echo $BASH_VERSION`, so that we can see which bash is running the code.

Comment: Yeah, i removed the quotes and still the same issue; and responding to the other comment I have bash 4.2.46(2)-release